# Reading content of a file and storing inside vector of uint8_t type

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file and store its content inside a vector of type `uint8_t`. I am unable to get the type of data stored inside my file seems data is encrypted. I am opening file in binary mode.

My code looks like this:

```
    vector<uint8_t>vec;
    streampos size;
    ifstream Myfile("sample.bin", std::ifstream::binary);
    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
            Myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
            size = Myfile.tellg();
            Myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            cout<<"size of file is"<<size<<"\n";
            Myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&vec[0]),size);

            Myfile.close();
    }
    cout<<vec.size();
    for(size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
            cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }
```

The code is getting compiled but I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after executing it. I am unable to debug it.

Comment: @DavidFong I was assuming there would already be an existing answer to this, so I went looking for that duplicate. However, I didn't find one, so ...

Comment: actually there are many questions with same issue, but as OP is usually not aware of the issue, they dont have titles "how to assign to a non-existing vector element?" but rather refer to some secondary issues, such as segfaults or reading from a file not working or something else.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I looked quite a bit but didn't really find anything that I would feel comfortable closing as a dupe against. As you say, there are many *related* questions, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole not sure if we really need a "How to resize a vector?" dupe target. Its something one can find easily while doing rtfm, though I am also glad about every time someone is helped to correctly use `std::vector`

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a dupe, but it's not so obvious. Even though the problem in the question is quite trivial, and maybe not very useful for others. Anyway, I suggest to close, leaving this comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:

```cpp
Myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&vec[0]),size);
```

Here, because the `vec` vector is *default* initialized (in `vector<uint8_t>vec;`), it will be an *empty* vector. This means that attempting to access its underlying data (*via* the address of its first element) is undefined behaviour (because there is no such data) and will (most likely) cause a memory access error (aka "segmentation fault") and your program crashes. <sup>1</sup>

In many circumstances, you can circumvent this by calling the constructor overload for `std::vector` that takes a `size_t count` argument (i.e., something like `vector<uint8_t> vec(size)`). However, in your case, that isn't possible, because the value of `size` isn't known at the point of the vector's declaration.

Instead, you can call the [`resize()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on your vector to allocate the required number of bytes (`uint8_t`) – **after** you have calculated the size required **and before** the call to `Myfile.read`.

Here's the inner block of your code with that allocation/resize added:

```cpp
    if (Myfile.is_open())
    {
        Myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        size = Myfile.tellg();
        Myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        std::cout << "size of file is" << size << "\n";

        vec.resize(static_cast<size_t>(size)); // Allocate required storage
        Myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&vec[0]), size);

        Myfile.close();
    }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that, although a `std::vector` object will 'grow' automatically when you add data to it through calls to `push_back()` and similar functions, the same is not true when access (read or write) is performed using the `[]` operator (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adrian 
My code is working now.